# How to schedule python script run from anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, scheduled-tasks

I want every twenty minutes python script to be run from anaconda prompt. i.e. I want command:

`python script.py --argument arg`

to be run every twenty minutes. I saw package called `schedule` and that I can run python scripts via Task Manager but those things seem to be not suitable for my problem (Task Manager can run `script.py` every twenty minutes, but there is not option to provide my argument `arg` to it).

Could you please help me with doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from a python script

```
import time

while True:
    os.system('python script.py --argument arg')
    time.sleep(1800)
```